# writing a tf::transform object to a file

Tags: c++, tensorflow, ros, ofstream

I'm attempting to do something resembling the following block of code:

```
tf::transform t;
initializeTransform(t);
std::ofstream f;
f.open("somefile");
f << t << std::endl;
f.close();
```

Assuming that I've properly set up that `f` and `t` when I'm trying to write `t` to `f`, how would I do so? I tried a number of variants of this, and all of them result in a huge wall of text to the effect that `ofstream` doesn't know how to handle a tf::transform object, which isn't too surprising.

Is there some way to make `ofstream` take arbitrary objects? Is there some format that I could readily convert it to that's more conducive to streaming? Ideally, if I convert it, I'd like to have a way to reversibly convert it to some matrix that I can pipe straight into and out of a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the operator
I'm not sure of the contents of the transform struct in this case, but assuming it is:

```
struct transform { float mat[16]; }
```

Then the implementation can be something like:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const tf::transform& t)
{
  os << t.mat[0];
  for(int i=1;i<16;++i) os << ',' << t.mat[i];
  return os;
}
```

Comment: "Implement that operator" is a more compact phrasing of one angle of the question, but not an answer.

Comment: Added an example.  The implementation depends on the contents of the data structure, but basically you break the operation into multiple uses of the << operator, until you're left with primitives.